# Resharper Unit Tests do not interact with Code Lens

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, codelens

Is there a way to let ReSharper have an effect to the Code Lens Part for the executed tests?
So, i want my tests that got executed by a resharper unit test session, to show the state in the unittest part of code lens.

Im using VS2015 Enterprise and ReSharper Ultimate v.2017.2

Any help is appreciated, maybe it isn't possible or im just blind and there is some option to set somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. The unit test Code Lens is hardcoded for the Visual Studio test runner, and isn't extensible.